# How to correctly apply distinctUntilChanged for DOM operations minimization

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, frp, rxjs

I'm trying to do a popup menu using RxJS, here is where I stopped: http://jsbin.com/coqulamamo/1/edit?html,js,output

I've mapped to 2 main eventstreams, `menuActivation` and `menuDeactivation`:

- `menuActivation` emits a popup container whenever any of its chidren emits `mouseenter` or `focusin`.
- `menuDeactivation` emits the last `menuActivation` element after its first `mouseleave` or the next time any non-descendent element emits `focusin`.

For each popup container on `menuActivation`, `active` class is appended; For each on `menuDeactivation`, `active` class is removed from the element.

So far, so good. But now, how do I prevent too much DOM operations? There is no need to activate a menu when it is already active, the same applies to deactivations, but I don't want to keep states in a Rx.Subject, there can be any length of popup menus distributed on the page.

I tried `.distinctUntilChanged()` but when a popup container is emitted sequentially in `menuActivation` and then in `menuDeactivation`, the next time the same popup won't be emitted on `menuActivation`.

Is there a way to allow a popup container to surpass `menuActivation.distinctUntilChanged()` after be project on `menuDeactivation`?

Comment: Please add code to the question instead of linking to it.  You can even use SO snippet to post functional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distinctUntilChanged` can only work on a single observable. To work around this you can create an observable which combines your two observables. Something like

```
var menuAct2 = menuActivation.map(function(menu) { return { type: "act", menu: menu}; })

var menuDeact2 = menuDeactivation.map(function(menu) { return { type: "deact", menu: menu}; })

var actDeact = menuAct2.merge(menuDeact2)
  .distinctUntilChanged(function (a) {return a;}, function (a, b) {
  return a.menu === b.menu && a.type === b.type;
});

actDeact
.filter(function (a) { return a.type === "act";})
.map(function (a) {return a.menu;})
.subscribe(function(menu) {
  console.log("Focou:", menu);
  menu.classList.add("MainMenu__ListContainer--Active");
});

actDeact
.filter(function (a) { return a.type === "deact";})
.map(function (a) {return a.menu;})
.subscribe(function(menu) {
  console.log("Desfocou:", menu);
  menu.classList.remove("MainMenu__ListContainer--Active");
});
```

You basically create an observable by merging your two observables, do a `distinctUntilChanged` on that observable, and split it back into two observables to use in the rest of your code.

Sorry if this is not proper javascript, I'm not too familiar with the language.